# Read MySQL blob in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, io, blob

Hi I have a problem with type after I get blob from my query, here is the code

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect("mysqlblah", "user", "pass", "db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

data = []
queryString = "SELECT * FROM contentindex where tag LIKE '" + contentType + "%'"
cursor.execute(queryString)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
columns = [t[0] for t in cursor.description]
for row in rows:
    jsonRow = {}
    i = 0
    for column in columns:
        if column == "created":
            jsonRow[column] = str(row[i])
        elif column == "icon":
            icon = row[i]
            print icon
            jsonRow[column] = "data:image/(jpg);base64," + base64.b64encode(icon.getvalue())
        else:
            jsonRow[column] = row[i]
        i = i + 1
    data.append(jsonRow)
```

This prints `<_io.BytesIO object at 0x01667810>` and then throws `'str' object has no attribute 'getvalue'` exception.

I'm pounding for days on this problem, any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This seems very strange. What happens if instead of `print icon` you try `print icon.getvalue()`?

Comment: I get this crash `'str' object has no attribute 'getvalue'`

Comment: The `BytesIO` stuff seems like a red herring. It appears you are dealing with a `str` object. Assuming `icon` is the binary string you want it to be, does `base64.b64encode(icon)` accomplish what you need?

Comment: Looks like it gives me base64 string. I guess this is what i want..

Comment: Is there any chance you have bad data in the database? Perhaps you accidentally saved the string representation of a `BytesIO` object to the database? (i.e. the BLOB literally holds the characters `"<_io.BytesIO object at 0x01667810>"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like MySQL converts the `BLOB` field type to a Python `str`.

Based on our conversation in the comments, I believe you have inadvertently stored a string with the value `"<_io.BytesIO object at 0x01667810>"` in this column rather than the actual data you wished to store. You can test whether this is the case in a couple of different ways:

```
print icon[0]  # I'm betting it will be '<'
print type(icon)  # Likely 'str'
```

In summary, it appears you have a data corruption issue as opposed to some sort of exotic issue with types.

Comment: I checked your theory and you are absolutely correct. I found my wrong code where I was saving and did not do getvalue on my BytesIO